# Getting memory address of class member variable (non-dynamic)

Tags: c++

I want to print the memory address (i.e. 0x7ffff0...) of a variable in my class, but it only gives me the value of the object.

I'm just doing this to learn. I don't think my syntax is incorrect. I try two ways and neither works. I would appreciate help on why this doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
public:
char i;
};

int main(){
test x;
x.i='w';
char * y = &(x.i);
cout<<"address : " <<&x.i<<endl;
cout<<"address : " <<y<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
address : w
address : w
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I will mark as resolved once I am allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the pointer to a void* before passing it to the stream.  You're passing a char* which is interpreted as a null-terminated string.

Comment: Isn't "&x.i" interpreted to be the address of x.i?

Comment: @user1762250: Yes, but in C, strings are null terminated pointers to char, and there is an overload of `operator<<` that will interpret `const char*` as if it was a string, printing the pointed to value (which in this case will cause undefined behavior, as there is no guarantee of null termination, that `const char*` is not a string, but the overload you are using expects it to be)

Comment: Yes &x.i is the address of x.i.  std::cout, however, sees that it is a pointer to a char so it tries to print a string.  Since the char isn't even null terminated, this is a memory overread which could crash or worse.  std::stream prints an address for a void*.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Is there some way (other than the void *) to have cout print an address without evaluating it as a string?

Comment: cast to an uintptr_t and use stream operators to print it in hex (std::hex)

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the pointer to an integer type. Then print the integer. Try intptr_t.